# Using ex-navigation with Exponent js, how do I clear the StackNavigation of a tab when the user navigates away?

Tags: javascript, react-native, exponentjs

I'm using ex-navigation with Exponent and React Native. I have a multi-tab TabNavigation, where each tab has its own StackNavigation element inside. When the user changes tabs in the TabNavigation, I'd like to reset the stack of the previous tab.

I can already reset the StackNavigation element using [popToTop](https://github.com/exponentjs/ex-navigation#stacknavigation-actions), but my issue is determining when the user changes tabs. Is there an emitted tab-change event, or route change event, that I can subscribe to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some help from the `ex-navigation` developers, I have found a way to clear the tab stack upon navigating away. We can attach an `onPress` handler to the `TabNavigation` component, and it will be passed the default event handler. After calling the default handler to change tabs, we can perform any other desired actions. Here's a version of a TabNavigation that clears the stack of the first tab when the user clicks any of the tabs:

```
export default class RootNavigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
  }

  onPress(switchTab) {
    switchTab();
    requestIdleCallback(() => {
      this.props.navigation.performAction(({stacks}) => {
        stacks("first").popToTop();
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TabNavigation initialTab="first">
          <TabNavigationItem id="first-tab" onPress={this.onPress}>
            <StackNavigation id="first" navigatorUID="first" initialRoute="first-route" />
          </TabNavigationItem>

          <TabNavigationItem id="second-tab" onPress={this.onPress}>
            <StackNavigation id="second" navigatorUID="second" initialRoute="second-route" />
          </TabNavigationItem>

          <TabNavigationItem id="third-tab" onPress={this.onPress}>
            <StackNavigation id="third" navigatorUID="third" initialRoute="third-route" />
          </TabNavigationItem>
        </TabNavigation>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Note that the stack we manipulate through `stacks("first")` must have both an `id` and `navigatorUID` set to `"first"`.